# check if given path is a subdirectory of another in golang

Tags: go

Say we have two paths:

`c:\foo\bar\baz` and `c:\foo\bar`

Is there any package/method that will help me determine if one is a subdirectory of another? I am looking at a cross-platform option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try and use [path.filepath.Rel()](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Rel):

```
func Rel(basepath, targpath string) (string, error)
```

> `Rel` returns a relative path that is lexically equivalent to `targpath` when joined to `basepath` with an intervening separator.
>   That is, `Join(basepath, Rel(basepath, targpath))` is equivalent to `targpath` itself

That means `Rel("c:\foo\bar", "c:\foo\bar\baz")` should be `baz`, meaning a subpath completely included in `c:\foo\bar\baz`, and without any '`../`'.
The same would apply for unix paths.

That would make `c:\foo\bar\baz` a subdirectory of `c:\foo\bar`.

Comment: Make sure to use `filepath.EvalSymlinks`

Comment: This only works if both paths are either absolute or relative. It doesn't if you mix it.

Comment: @maja Good point. I suppose you need to convert one of your parameter (the relative path) into an absolute path, then?

Comment: It definitely improves it, but I'm not sure it's correct in all cases, since `filepath.Abs` explicitly states that it doesn't return a unique representation.

Comment: Another issue with this answer: You not only need to check for the `../` prefix, but also if the result is `..`. This can happen for `Rel("rel/path", "rel")`.

Comment: @maja Good point. Could you edit this answer with a more robust code?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't found a reliable solution for all types of paths, but the best you can get is by using `filepath.Rel` as VonC suggested.

It works if both filepaths are either absolute or relative (mixing is not allowed) and works on both Windows and Linux:

```
func SubElem(parent, sub string) (bool, error) {
    up := ".." + string(os.PathSeparator)

    // path-comparisons using filepath.Abs don't work reliably according to docs (no unique representation).
    rel, err := filepath.Rel(parent, sub)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    if !strings.HasPrefix(rel, up) && rel != ".." {
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, nil
}
```

Absolute windows paths that start with a drive letter will require an additional check though.

Comment: thanks.  might also want to consider checking for parent == sub

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function [path.filepath.Match()](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match)

> Match reports whether name matches the shell file name pattern.

For example:

```
pattern := "C:\foo\bar" + string(filepath.Separator) + "*"
matched, err := filepath.Match(pattern, "C:\foo\bar\baz")
```

Where `matched` should be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

If you first canonicalize both paths by calling `filepath.EvalSymlinks()` and `filepath.Abs()` on them, you can simply append a '/' to each one, since the UNIX kernel itself forbids a '/' within a path component. At this point you can simply use `strings.HasPrefix()` on the two paths, in either order.

Comment: This wont work on case-insensitive file systems.

Comment: This doesn't work. filepath.Abs explicitly states that it doesn't return a unique representation of a path.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. This checks if either is a sub-directory of the other. Try changing values of both base and path and the results should be valid.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    base := "/b/c/"
    path := "/a/b/c/d"

    if len(base) > len(path) {
        base, path = path, base
    }

    rel, err := filepath.Rel(base, path)
    fmt.Printf("Base %q: Path %q: Rel %q Err %v\n", base, path, rel, err)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("PROCEED")
        return
    }

    if strings.Contains(rel, "..") {
        fmt.Println("PROCEED")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("DENY")
}
```

Comment: This pretty much the same as my answer, with the difference that it's broken. Try it with a directory name like "/dir1/..containsDots../dir3"